# Task Scheduler Not Running Selenium .bat at Startup

Tags: windows, batch-file, selenium, windows-server-2012, taskscheduler

I have a .bat script that launches a Selenium Server. It's setup with the Task Scheduler to run on startup but it doesn't run. When I open the Scheduler, select the task, and click "run" it will execute fine. Does anyone know what may be preventing a task from running at startup?

Here are screenshots of the task scheduler settings.

[Triggers Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7fL9.png)

[Actions Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I22GX.png)

Thanks for any help

Comment: You basically want to start a service.  What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: according to the tag, @MikeJRamsey56, Sonny is using windows server 2012

Comment: Good catch. :$ Perhaps this will [help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/137890).  I know the link says Server 2000 but [this](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/1043-71-program-startup-windows-server-2012) says it still works the same way.